# Insert field in Custom Metadata Type with Relationship field using Metadata API

Tags: apex, soql, metadata-relationship

I have Custom Metadata Type with Metadata Relationship field.
I'm trying to insert a new record in it, it runs successfully with no errors, but doesn't insert the row!

Here is my code:

```
Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
   customMetadata.fullName = 'Voicesense_score__mdt.1';//+scoreId; 
   customMetadata.label = 'XX1';//+scoreId;

    Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();  
    customField.field = 'scoreId__c' ;
    customField.value = 1;
    customMetadata.values.add(customField);

    customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();  
    customField.field = 'Status__c' ;
    customField.value = 1;
    customMetadata.values.add(customField);

    customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();  
    customField.field = 'Voicesense_score_name_Id__c' ;
//    string soqlQuery = 'SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM Voicesense_score_name__mdt WHERE ID__c='+vsScoreNameId;
    customField.value ='X1';
    customMetadata.values.add(customField);
```

'X1' is the QualifiedApiName of an existing parent field.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this all of your code? You don't enqueue a Metadata API deployment here.

Comment: No, it's not. but this is the problematic code, because the other code works for different Custom Metadata Types.